# Why chart print blank in div tag?

Tags: asp.net

I'm beginner in asp.net ,want to show to user any data with chart and user can be print that chart,chart control html code this:

```
<div id="MainContent_divl" class="div_l" style="float:left;direction:ltr;text-align:Left;">
            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button3_Click" />
            <input type="button" onclick="PrintDiv();" value="پرینت" />
            <br />
            <div align="center">
                <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label" BackColor="Red" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
                <br />
                <br />

                <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label" BackColor="Blue" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <br />

                <asp:Chart ID="Chart1" runat="server" Height="579px" Width="4177px">
                    <Series>
                        <asp:Series Name="Series1"></asp:Series>
                    </Series>
                    <ChartAreas>
                        <asp:ChartArea Name="ChartArea1"></asp:ChartArea>
                    </ChartAreas>
                    <BorderSkin BorderWidth="3" />
                </asp:Chart>

        </div>
```

and this is a print button code:

```
<input type="button" onclick="PrintDiv();" value="پرینت" />
```

and this is javasript code for that purpose:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function PrintDiv() {
            var divContents = document.getElementById("MainContent_divl").innerHTML;
            var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=200,width=400');
            printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title>DIV Contents</title>');
            printWindow.document.write('</head><body >');
            printWindow.document.write(divContents);
            printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');
            printWindow.document.close();
            printWindow.print();
        }
    </script>
```

but when want to print,chart show blank in print page,what happen?how can i solve that?thanks.